# Javascript arrays data not displayed in HTML table after clicking button submit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a button submit work after I click submit. Currently the problem is that when I click submit, it did redirect me to the corresponding pages but the data from the arrays is not displayed in the html table. I tried adding it manually and it works but when when I tried implementing adding data to array by means of  *form*. It doesn't work. When I tried putting the code **addToHTML()** outside of the **function submitButton()**, it works. But when I remove it now, it's not displayed and there are no errors shown. I am wondering what did I do wrong here ? The following are my html and javascript code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Book Object</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Book template</h1>

    <form>
        <table id="book-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Title </th>
                    <th> Author </th>
                    <th> Pages </th>
                    <th> Read </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="tbody">
                <tr id="dataContainer"></tr>
            </tbody> 
        </table>
    </form>

    <a href="addbook.html">
        <button id="add-book"> Add Book </button>
    </a>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

script.js

```
// Main Book object model
function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;  
}

// Library object model
function Library() {
    this.myLibrary = [];
    
    this.addToLibrary = function(myLibrary) {
        this.myLibrary.push(myLibrary);
    }
}

// Create new book object
let book1 = new Book('Awaken the Giant Within', 'Tony Robbins', '351', 'already read');
let book2 = new Book('Think and Grow Rich', 'Napoleon Hill', '271', 'currently reading');
let book3 = new Book('Rich Dad Poor Dad', 'Robert T. Kiyosaki', '289', 'finish read');
let book4 = new Book('Atomic Habits', 'James Clear', '279', 'finish read');
let book5 = new Book('The Outliers', 'Malcom Gladwell', '311', 'currently reading');

// Create new library object
let library = new Library();

// Add books to the empty array
library.addToLibrary(book1);
library.addToLibrary(book2);
library.addToLibrary(book3);
library.addToLibrary(book4);
library.addToLibrary(book5);

// Function to add main Book to HTML content
function addToHTML() {
    for (let i=0; i < library.myLibrary.length ; i++ ) {
            let tbody = document.querySelector('#tbody');
            let content = 
                `<tr>
                    <td id='title'> ${library.myLibrary[i].title} </td>
                    <td id='author'> ${library.myLibrary[i].author} </td>
                    <td id='pages'> ${library.myLibrary[i].pages} </td>
                    <td id='read'> ${library.myLibrary[i].read} </td>
                </tr>`

            tbody.innerHTML += content;
    }
}

// Submit button

// Add event listener to submit button

function submitButton() {
    let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let jsTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
        let jsAuthor = document.getElementById('author').value;
        let jsPages = document.getElementById('pages').value;
        let jsRead = document.getElementById('read').value;

        let book1 = new Book(jsTitle, jsAuthor, jsPages, jsRead);
        library.addToLibrary(book1);
        addToHTML();
    })
}
```

addbook.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add Book Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="addbookform.css">
</head>

<body onload="submitButton()">
    <h1>Add Book Form</h1>
    
    <form action='index.html' method='post'>
            <p>Title:</p>
              <input type='text' name='title' id='title'>
    
            <p>Author: </p>
              <input type='text' name='author' id='author'>
    
            <p>Pages:</p>
              <input type='text' name='pages' id='pages'>

            <p>Read:</p>
              <input type='text' name='read' id='read'>

            <br/>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' id='submit'>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no item with id=submit in your html.

Comment: @mykaf Pardon, i've updated the submit button in the code above

Comment: As soon as your form is submitted, the screen is refreshed and the html resets. You'll need to prevent the default form submit if you don't want the screen to refresh.

Comment: @mykaf Do I have to put all the content just in one html file ? because currently when I tried adding data, it will redirect me to another page to fill in a form. and after the required info is filled in only then the form is submitted

Comment: @mykaf I tried changing the function in the function submitButton() to function getTarget(e) { e.preventDefault()  .... } and now the error is TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Comment: There are many many ways to approach this, so, no, you don't *have* to put all the content just in one html file. It's hard to determine what the error is without seeing the complete version of the update you've made.

Comment: @mykaf the error was referring to the function addToHTML () { .... tbody.innerHTML += content; } and to addtoHTML() in function submitButton() { }

Comment: If you replaced your first html section with the second, there is no element with id=tbody.

Comment: FYI: `let` is when you are going to change the value. You should be using `const` when you declare most of your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add Book Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Add Book Form</h1>


    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type='text' name='title' id='title'>

    <label for="author">Author: </label>
    <input type='text' name='author' id='author'>

    <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
    <input type='text' name='pages' id='pages'>

    <label for="read">Read:</label>
    <input type='text' name='read' id='read'>

    <br />
    <button onclick="submitButton()" value='submit' id='submit'>
        Submit
    </button>


    <br>
    <table id="book-table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Title </th>
                <th> Author </th>
                <th> Pages </th>
                <th> Read </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

<script>
    function submitButton() { 
        let jsTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
        let jsAuthor = document.getElementById('author').value;
        let jsPages = document.getElementById('pages').value;
        let jsRead = document.getElementById('read').value;

        let tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

        let tr = document.createElement('tr')

        let data = `
        <td>
            ${jsTitle}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${jsAuthor}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${jsPages}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${jsRead}
        </td>`

        tr.innerHTML = data
        document.getElementById('tbody').append(tr)

    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried the solution but then the error, TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'append') shown

Comment: the code is working,you can try to copy all codes and running it, the outpu will same if you run code snippet

Answer (score 1):

you need to prevent your browser from the event action, so you you can use `preventDefault() function` to ignore the page redirection.

**Edit**:

I've just used CSS display property to display the form and then hide it on submit, to show the table,

you can use it on your own, so you can include your input at the same page as it supposed to be, also you can use it in a modal instead of use it like that or just add a button to display it upon click

```js
let next = document.querySelector('input[value="next"]');
let subbtn = document.querySelector(`input[value='submit']`)
let newBook = {
  jsTitle: '',
  jsAuthor: '',
  jsPages: '',
  jsRead: '',
  jsPrice: '',
  jsUrl: ''
}
next.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  newBook.jsTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
  newBook.jsAuthor = document.getElementById('author').value;
  newBook.jsPages = document.getElementById('pages').value;
  newBook.jsRead = document.getElementById('read').value;
  document.querySelector('#page1').style = 'display:none'
  document.querySelector('#page2').style = 'display:block'
})
subbtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  newBook.jsPrice = document.getElementById('price').value;
  newBook.jsUrl = document.getElementById('url').value;
  document.querySelector('#page2').style = 'display:none'
  document.querySelector('#page3').style = 'display:block'
  document.querySelector(`tbody`).innerHTML =  `<tr>${Object.entries(newBook).map((arr,index) => '<td>'+arr[1]+'</td>').toString().replaceAll(',','')}</tr>`
})
```

```css
#page1 {
display:block;
}
#page2 {
display:none;
}

#page3 {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1">
  <form action="page.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" id='title' placeholder='title' required />
    <input type="text" id='author' placeholder='author' required />
    <input type="text" id='pages' placeholder='pages' required />
    <input type="text" id='read' placeholder='read' required />
    <input type="button" value="next" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="page2">
  <form action="page.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" id='price' placeholder='price' required />
    <input type="text" id='url' placeholder='url' required />
    <input type="button" value="submit" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="page3">
  <table border="1px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>author</th>
        <th>pages</th>
        <th>read</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>url</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the solution above and now getting the error ...TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Comment: Do I have to put all the content just in one html file ? because currently when I tried adding data, it will redirect me to another page to fill in a form. and after the required info is filled in only then the form is submitted and it will redirect me to the corresponding pages where I want the data is displayed in the html table

Comment: `#tbody` is not a such selector in your displayed code, so the `addToHTML()` function returns error, where should the table be at your code? 
if you need to collect data from this page, and move to another page, so you need to escape the submit process from this page, and just transfer the data to the other page with it's content, or just use css display property to hide the first inputs, and show the next inputs

Comment: it's weird also that you're calling `submitButton()` function at your body load !!
`<body onload="submitButton()">`
you need clarify, how's your work done?
also the addToHTML() is targeting the first html page, so you can't target it from this page, you can just transfer the data to the other page and set the other page to get this params on load, then it can then submit render it into the table,

Comment: the table initially is at the index.html and to add data to the data, i loop through the arrays as seen in my function addToHTML() function

Comment: I am calling the submitButton() on body because previously without it I get an error that Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. at the same time, i've put the script at the bottom most in body. So I do that to fix that error

Comment: @JabriJuhinin
check the answer i did edited it with snippet so you can try, it could help you

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because It's sending a POST request when you click the submit button and hence the page refreshes.

You can ignore that behavior by listening to submit event of form input rather than the button click and preventing the default behavior of the form.js

```js
const submitEventHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}

function submitButton() {
    let form = document.getElementById('formid');
    form.addEventListener('submit', submitEventHandler)
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution, submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); but now the error is showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Comment: It's not a click event. It's a submit event. Also, make sure you have referenced the form element properly via the submit variable
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp